# how can i display scatter point values on click and hover using matplotlib? iam new to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, hover, scatter

here is what i am trying to do:

this is the data i am using for color reference
#create list of cqi column in float format

```
li=[]

for x in data.lte_cqi_cw0_1:
    li.append(float(x))
```

i created a list for x and y axis data from the imported csv

```
#create x and y axis data
x = []
y = []
for a in data.positioning_lon:
    x.append(float(a))
for a in data.positioning_lat:
    y.append(float(a))
```

setting color condition

```
c = np.where(data.lte_cqi_cw0_1 < 7, 'r', 'g')

#plot the map
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
scatter=ax.scatter(x,y,c=c)
```

**i am using this method to display the value of each point. i want to use on_click event and hover event to display values based on mouse movement.**

```
#display each point value        
for i, value in enumerate(li):
    
    annot = ax.annotate(value,(x[i], y[i]))
    annot.set_visible(False)


#set legend
red = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label="0 to 7 - " + str(low_per) + "%")
green = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label="7 to 15 - " + str(high_per) + "%")
plt.legend(handles=[red , green ])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

okay i have found the soluiton.
iam using the following annote method.

```
annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="- 
>"))
annot.set_visible(False)
```

then defining a function to update annotate value depending upon index i will recievec from click event.

```
def update_annot(ind):
    pos = scatter.get_offsets()[ind]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = " CQI {}".format(" ".join([str(round(li[ind],2))]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor((c[ind]))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)
    return text
```

the following onpick function is working fine for my objective.

```
def onpick(event):
    #vis = annot.get_visible()
    #annot.set_visible(True)
    global ind
    ind = event.ind[-1]
    print("first value ind"+str(ind))

    update_annot(ind)
    annot.set_visible(True)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    #print (len(ind))
    #print('onpick points:', update_annot(ind))
```

I have figured out keypress event also which is as follows.

```
def press(event):
    key = event.key
    sys.stdout.flush()
    global ind
    if key == 'left':

        ind += 1
        print("2nd value ind" + str(ind))
        update_annot(ind)
        annot.set_visible(True)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    elif key == 'right':

        ind -= 1
        print("3rd value ind" + str(ind))
        update_annot(ind)
        annot.set_visible(True)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

then connecting both onpick and keypress functions to matplotlib's internal function.

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
```

full code can be found [here](https://khanbarkat.com/blog/plot-lte-parameters-using-python-matplotlib-pandas-and-numpy/)

Comment: full code can be found here [link](https://khanbarkat.com/blog/plot-lte-parameters-using-python-matplotlib-pandas-and-numpy/)